# Tecknet mouse loses Bluetooth connection after being idle for a short while

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, 20.10

I am using Ubuntu MATE 20.10, having upgraded recently from 20.04 to try to solve this problem, to no avail. Using the same mouse in Windows 10 it does not lose connection after being idle for lengthy periods of time. Hence the problem does not lie with the mouse.
My Arteck keyboard also loses Bluetooth connection after a period of idleness, but it takes longer before timing out.
When researching answers to similar problems I have seen that some people have had success by blacklisting their device in /etc/default/tlp. I do not have this file in my installation, so that is not an option for me.
In both cases, (mouse and keyboard) they do not automatically reconnect when I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard: I have to manually reconnect them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with a Tecknet Mouse.
You can try turning off Sleep mode and see if it stays connected.

I'm using the BlueZ 5.54 stack that is in Chromebook. Ubuntu is likely the same.

MY guess is its the BM30X driver has not been properly tested with BlueZ 5.54 for linux and derivatives.